# Angular: converting multiple files to an in-memory tarball

Tags: angular, typescript, tar

I am writing a custom plugin for the [`Uppy` library](https://uppy.io/docs/quick-start/). Since our use-case is to often upload thousands of several smaller files rather then just a few files, we have chosen to tar the files together into a single file to our server which then untars them.

But it seems we are completely stuck with writing the tarring process. We have been working with at least 5 different tar libraries and they all either want to save to memory (which we cannot do in Angular, the `fs` module is not integrated in the browser) or they are mere streams which are of no use to us.

Currently we are working with the [tar-stream library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar-stream) to generate a tarball.But the documentation on all of these packages is practically non existent. All code is untyped (being raw JS) and the handful of documentation available is not useful to us. I cannot seem to find a way to get like a `Blob` from the `pack` variable in their documentation.

**So therefore this question to see if anyone has been able yet to make tarball files in Angular (in-memory).**